# PowerShell just Hangs

Tags: windows, powershell

Anyone else have problems when running a PowerShell script, where the script just hangs in one spot until you hit Enter or something on the console window?   This happens to me all the time, and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Check if your script has breaks, and read up on the cmdlets you're using and see if they have "force" options.  If you can, try to edit your question to be more specific.  I'm not sure it meets SF's quality standards as it is now.

Comment: @Colyn1337 +1 - Unless you have a concrete example of a script that causes your powershell session to "hang", this is not really SF Q&A material

Comment: Yup, definitely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen *all the time* to my sessions.

I often find it's because I've selected some text in the console, sometimes by accident, and it causes the PS console window to stop outputting text.

You can tell if this is the case by the window's title; it will be something like `Select Windows PowerShell` instead of just `Windows PowerShell`.

Paused:
[image]

Not paused:
[image]

Comment: This is usually more of a buffering issue when looking on the console.  If you output to a file you shouldn't run into the issue.  If you hit enter a few times, the output starts dumping.  Infinite loops will eventually crash.

Comment: Nope, just confirmed by running`1..10 | %{random; sleep 2} >> output.txt`.  Even after 60 seconds, the script still appears to be hung even though the task has completed (verified by seeing if 10 random numbers exist in `output.txt`).

Comment: Right, but hitting `enter` causes the selection to disappear and returns the window to its "normal" state.

Comment: OP even mentions that hitting `enter` causes the script to 'resume'.